# Select many counts in one query using constructor

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, constructor, named-query

I'm tryin to count some information and would like to insert them in my db via namedquery using a constructor
This is the code :

```
@NamedQuery(name = PageEntity.FIND_ALL_PAGES_BY_TYPE, query = "SELECT DISTINCT new PageEntity
(e.id,e.backendId,e.name,e.pageType,e.updatedOn,e.updatedBy,e.mobileEnabled,e.desktopEnabled,e.mobileEnabledBy,e.desktopEnabledBy,e.mobileEnabledOn,e.desktopEnabledOn,
    (SELECT COUNT(sc) FROM SectionContentEntity sc, PageSectionEntity ps WHERE ps.section.archived = false AND ps.page = e AND ps.section = sc.section), 
    (SELECT COUNT(sc) FROM SectionContentEntity sc, PageSectionEntity ps WHERE ps.section.archived = false AND ps.page = e AND ps.section = sc.section AND sc.desktopEnabled = false AND sc.mobileEnabled = false),
    (SELECT COUNT(sc) FROM SectionContentEntity sc, PageSectionEntity ps WHERE ps.section.archived = false AND ps.page = e AND ps.section = sc.section AND sc.desktopEnabled = true),
    (SELECT COUNT(sc) FROM SectionContentEntity sc, PageSectionEntity ps WHERE ps.section.archived = false AND ps.page = e AND ps.section = sc.section AND sc.mobileEnabled = true), 
    (SELECT COUNT(ps) FROM PageSectionEntity ps WHERE ps.section.archived = false AND ps.page = e),
    (SELECT COUNT(ps) FROM PageSectionEntity ps WHERE ps.section.archived = false AND ps.page = e AND ps.mobileEnabled = true),
    (SELECT COUNT(ps) FROM PageSectionEntity ps WHERE ps.section.archived = false AND ps.page = e AND ps.desktopEnabled = true)
) FROM PageEntity e  WHERE e.archived=false AND e.removed=false AND e.pageType IN (:pageTypes) ORDER BY e.id"),
```

and here is the errot i get :

```
<pre>java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: The transaction has been marked rollback only because the bean encountered a non-application exception :org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException : Your query on type &quot;class com.moutawadia.seekeane.bu.bo.model.country.cms.page.PageSectionEntity&quot; with filter &quot;SELECT new PageEntity(e.backendId, (SELECT COUNT(ps) FROM PageSectionEntity ps WHERE ps.section.archived = false)) FROM PageEntity e WHERE e.archived=false AND e.removed=false AND e.pageType IN (:pageTypes) GROUP BY e.backendId&quot; is invalid.  Your select and having clauses must only include aggregates or values that also appear in your grouping clause. while invoking public com.moutawadia.fwk.jee.model.json.exchanges.ResponseJSON com.moutawadia.seekeane.bu.bo.services.entrypoint.country.cms.webstrategy.page.CountryWebPageWebService.findAllPagesByType(com.moutawadia.fwk.jee.model.json.exchanges.RequestJSON) with params [RequestJSON [action=null, executedByApp=, executedByUser=, executedByDevice=, backendId=, args=[MAIN]]].
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.onMessage(AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.java:116)
org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:324)
org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:240)
org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.onMessage(CxfRsHttpListener.java:180)
org.apache.openejb.server.rest.RsServlet.service(RsServlet.java:53)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```